# C programming on IAR- timestamp Conversion to readable format

Tags: unix-timestamp

I am using Z-stack-CC2530-2.5 for developing Zigbee-based application. I've come across a timestmap conversion problem.

I am using osal_ConvertUTCTime method to convert a uint32 timestamp value to timestampStruct as follows:

```
osal_ConvertUTCTime(& timestampStruct, timestamp);
```

The Struct is defined as follows:

```
typedef struct{
uint8 seconds;
uint8 min;
uint8 hour;
uint8 day;
uint8 month;
uint16 year;
} UTCTimeStruct
```

My Question:

How to convert the Struct's content to be written on the UART port in a human readable format ?

Example:

```
HalUARTWrite (Port0, timestampStruct, len)     // Output: 22/1/2013 12:05:45
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have the prototype of the function HalUartWrite at the moment, but I googled it and someone used it as this:

```
HalUARTWrite(DEBUG_UART_PORT, "12345", 6);
```

so I guess the second argument must be a pointer to char. You can't just pass a struct UTCTimeStruct variable into the second argument. If you just need to output the raw data to the serial port. You need to cast the struct into char * in order to make the compiler happy. But generally, this is bad practice. This might not be a problem in your case as you work in a 8-bit processor that all the struct fields are either a char or a short. In general, if you cast a struct into a char * and print it out, due to struct padding, you get a lot of nonsense characters between your struct fields.

OK. A bit off topic. Back to your question, you need to convert the struct into a friendly string yourself. Because you know your output string is of format "22/1/2013 12:05:45" which has fixed length, you can simply declare a char[] of that length. And manually fill in the numbers by bit-manipulating the uint32 timestamp value. After that, you can pass the char[] into the second argument and the exact length into the third argument.